# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement djangocms

Tags: python, pip, django-cms

Trying to follow a [screencast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NbsRVfLCE1U) to install DjangoCMS:

```
$ mkvirtualenv modern_business
$ pip install djangocms
```

and got an error:

[image]

I am using python 2.7. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to install django cms installer:

```
    (.envtest)$ pip install djangocms-installer
    Collecting djangocms-installer
      Downloading djangocms_installer-0.9.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (57kB)
        100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 628kB/s 
    Collecting argparse (from djangocms-installer)
      Downloading argparse-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting dj-database-url>=0.4 (from djangocms-installer)
      Downloading dj-database-url-0.4.1.tar.gz
      Successfully built dj-database-url tzlocal
.....
.....
    Installing collected packages: argparse, dj-database-url, six, pytz, tzlocal, djangocms-installer
    Successfully installed argparse-1.4.0 dj-database-url-0.4.1 djangocms-installer-0.9.3 pytz-2016.7 six-1.10.0 tzlocal-1.3
```

As per the doc here: http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/introduction/install.html